# QT qml TextField is not showing cursor when loaded first time

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtextedit

I am developing QT cross flat form application for Ubuntu and Windows. My Question is simple but as bit new to QT, i am not able to figure it out. I have bellow code in QML. I am using QT `TextField` in my qml. When QML is loaded for first time i want `id_username` TextField should show cursor by default at initial position (0) which is not happening. When i click same TextField using mouse, cursor is visible at initial position. I am doing `focus: true` which is not helpful. Next, i added `cursorVisible: true` with that cursor is visible when qml is loaded, but i am not able to type anything(Input anything) till i click on the `TextField`.

```
TextField
   {
      id: id_username
      objectName: "id_username"
      placeholderText: qsTr("username")
      color: "#000000"
      font.pixelSize: 20
      cursorPosition: 0
      selectByMouse: true
      anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
      focus: true
      background: Rectangle
      {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        implicitWidth: 200
        border.color: id_username.focus ? "#000000": "#36404e"
        border.width: id_username.focus ? 2: 1
        radius: id_instruction.height / 4
      }
    }
```

Please let me know what i am doing wrong. Is there any onLoad function from where can call `forceActiveFocus()`

Comment: QMetaObject::invokeMethod(m_pWindow->findChild<QObject*>("username"), "forceActiveFocus") 

Activating focus from C++ code as above is working fine. Same thing how can we achieve only in QML. (Added comment as it may give some hint to readers)

Comment: _Is there any onLoad function?_ [`Component.onCompleted`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#completed-signal)

Comment: This code works for me ie the control has focus on app start. You cat try `Component.onCompleted: forceActiveFocus()` to force that.

Comment: You should provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

try this in `TextField`:

```
onVisibleChanged: if(visible) id_username.forceActiveFocus()
```

Reference link - http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/62655-How-to-gain-focus-onto-TextEdit-in-QML